# Time taken to complete a piece of work

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**A** can complete a piece of work in **80 days**. He worked work for **10 days** , after that **B** completed the remaining work in **42 days**.
If **A** and **B** work together how many days will it take them to complete the entire piece of work?

**a)30 

b)25 

c)40 

d)none of these**

As per my solution the answer is **d** option but i still doubt my solution. Please help to find the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A completed $\frac{10}{80} = \frac 18$ of the work. Then B completed $\frac 78$ of the work in 42 days. So that means that he'll complete the whole work for:

$$\frac 78 x = 42$$
$$\frac 78x \frac87 = 42 \cdot \frac 87$$
$$ x = 48$$

We know that A will do the whole work for 80 days so for 1 day he'll finish $\frac {1}{80}$ of the work, while B will complete $\frac {1}{48}$

Now we have:

$$\frac {x}{80} + \frac {x}{48} = 1$$

Now you can continue on your own. Solve the equation for x to obtain the number of days.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ worked for 10 days, and hence completed $\frac 18$ of the project. $\frac 78$ of the project was then completed by $B$ in $42$ days. B then could complete the entire project in $x$ days, where $$\dfrac 78 x = 42 \iff x = \dfrac 87\cdot 42 = 56\;\text{days}$$

Let $y$ be the number of days to complete the project if both work together. Then we need only solve for:

$$\dfrac y{80} + \dfrac y{48} = 1$$ $$\dfrac{3y + 5y}{240} = 1 \iff 8y = 240 \iff y = 30$$
So the correct answer is $$(a)\quad  30$$

Answer (score 1):

Table approach I found to solve these sort of problems without much effort  and without equations and variables (assume a convenient number as total work initially and solve . I assumed it as 80 so that terms cancel to an extent, for example 80/80 = 1   :) ). I have added reason in brackets for you to follow  the table easily.

[image]

So answer is 30 . so option a